# How to upload video in Quill Editor?

Tags: quill, react-quill, ngx-quill

Currently, we are able to upload image using Quill Editor. which is base64 but we can upload that usign image handler. like this below:

```
modules: {
    toolbar: {
      container: '#toolbar',
      handlers: {
        'image': imageHandler
      }
    }
  },
```

the offical image handler is here:

```
function () {
  let fileInput = this.container.querySelector('input.ql-image[type=file]');
  if (fileInput == null) {
    fileInput = document.createElement('input');
    fileInput.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    fileInput.setAttribute('accept', 'image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp, image/x-icon');
    fileInput.classList.add('ql-image');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
      if (fileInput.files != null && fileInput.files[0] != null) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          let range = this.quill.getSelection(true);
          this.quill.updateContents(new Delta()
            .retain(range.index)
            .delete(range.length)
            .insert({ image: e.target.result })
          , Emitter.sources.USER);
          fileInput.value = "";
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
      }
    });
    this.container.appendChild(fileInput);
  }
  fileInput.click();
}
```

My question is how to upload video instead?